# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 377826: invalid start byte

Tags: windows, git, github, encoding, utf-8

I am getting the following error while executing the below code snippet exactly at the line `if uID in repo.git.log():`,
the problem is in `repo.git.log()`, I have looked at all the similar questions on Stack Overflow which suggests to use `decode("utf-8")`.

how do I convert `repo.git.log()` into `decode("utf-8")`?

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 377826: invalid start byte
```

Relavant code:

```
..................
uID = gerritInfo['id'].decode("utf-8")                                            
if uID in repo.git.log():
        inwslist.append(gerritpatch)      
.....................


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/prj/host_script/script.py", line 1417, in <module>
    result=main()
  File "/prj/host_script/script.py", line 1028, in main
    if uID in repo.git.log():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 431, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 802, in _call_process
    return self.execute(make_call(), **_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 610, in execute
    stdout_value = stdout_value.decode(defenc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 377826: invalid start byte
```

Comment: What Python module provides the `repo.git.log()` call? What version of Python is this? What is the **full** traceback of the exception?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - it is happening in Python 2.7.3 and Python 2.7.5,updated the quesiton with full traceback

Comment: The error happens way down in the bowels of the `repo.git.log()` command, I think because the output produced by the `git` command doesn't produce UTF-8. That could be because the git log contains non-UTF-8 data, or for a different reason. I don't know what project provides the `git` package however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - can we do something like repo.git.log = repo.git.log(encode('utf-8')) ..or strip of the right single quotation mark..what would be hte syntax for that?

Comment: You can't, no. I don't know what hit command is run or what influences the codecs used here.

Comment: I don't know what `git.py` you have but in `stdout_value = stdout_value.decode(defenc)` that `defenc` is interesting.  The name suggests "default encoding", so there appears to be a knob you can turn to set that `git.py` to expect different encodings for different commit messages.

Comment: what would be the value inplace of defenc to convert to utf6 codec

Comment: @torek: it just picks the system default: https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/master/git/compat.py#L26

Comment: According to the [git documenation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) git does not enforce any encodings, but UTF-8 is 'preferred'. The same documentation also shows that it is possible to configure git to output a specific codec; `i18n.logoutputencoding` specifically.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - any idea who to change the repo.git.log() to output utf-8 format?

Answer (score 44):

Use `encoding='cp1252'` will solve the issue.

Comment: This solved it for me!  As simple as reading in the file with this encoding.

Answer (score 23):

0x92 is a smart quote(’) of Windows-1252. It simply doesn't exist in unicode, therefore it can't be decoded.

Maybe your file was edited by a Windows machine which basically caused this problem?

Comment: thats my question too,how to make sure repo.git.log() has the right character encoding to get rid of this error?

Comment: 0x92 in Windows-1252 is simply one encoding for the [U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://codepoints.net/U+2019) codepoint in Unicode. To state that it doesn't exist in Unicode is.. incorrect; in UTF8 it should be encoded as 0xE2 0x80 0x99. If this *is* about data encoded as CP-1252 then that just means there is an encoding error somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

After good research, I got the solution. In my case, **`datadump.json`** file was having the issue.

- Simply Open the file in notepad format
- Click on save as option
- Go to encoding section below & Click on "UTF-8"
- Save the file.

Now you can try running the command. You are good to go :)

For your reference, I have attached images below.

[Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsLiH.png)

[Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usyPh.png)

[Step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0K19.png)

Answer (score 0):

0x92 does not exist in the encoding UTF-8.  As Exceen stated in his answer 0x92 is used in Windows-1252 as a smart quote.  The way to resolve this is to use the windows 1252 encoding or to update the smart quote to a normal quote.