# Read text file returns UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in Python

Tags: python, character-encoding

I'm reading a text file using Python3 even I have mentioned `encoding` but it retruns:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 96: invalid start byte
>   [05/May/2018 03:35:45] "POST /app/ HTTP/1.1" 500 14383

It's not a duplicate but it's specific to `byte 0x92`.

Here's what I have tried:

```
txt = Path(text_path).read_text(encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your textfile probably isn't encoded in utf-8. You might want to try a different encoding, e.g. `encoding='cp1252'`

Comment: Thank you, you save my search.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Exceen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419477/8890345)'s answer on a related question, that's a "smart quote" in the Win-1252 encoding.