# I keep getting UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read monthly csv file but for some reason, I keep getting this error.

This is my code below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
 
for file in os.listdir("Performance_Data"):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        df = pd.concat([df , pd.read_csv(os.path.join("Performance_Data", file))], axis=0 )
        
df.head()
```

What do I do?

Comment: It may not be a utf-8 encoded file.  You can open it in `notepad++` and at the bottom it will show the encoding.  Also ensure that it is in fact a comma delimited file and not tab or |  If you see a diff encoding just use `encoding='utf-16'` or whatever it is in the read_csv

Comment: I am the only one who can't read the error?

Comment: Why don't you accept the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas assumes by default that your file is encoded in UTF-8. Your file is encoded in Windows-1252. You can tell Pandas to use this encoding by

```py
pd.read_csv(os.path.join("Performance_Data", file), encoding='cp1252')
```

Detecting the encoding of a file automatically is a bit tricky, but you can use a package called "chardet". For your code, it could look like this:

```py
import os

import chardet
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in os.listdir("Performance_Data"):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        with open(file, "rb") as fp:
            encoding = chardet.detect(fp.read())["encoding"]
        df = pd.concat(
            [
                df,
                pd.read_csv(os.path.join("Performance_Data", file), encoding=encoding),
            ],
            axis=0,
        )

df.head()
```

**References**

- Pandas [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) documentation.
- [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 377826: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50185587/4339099), a relevant earlier question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for this, the code ran but however, I got this error as a follow up 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 253698: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Maybe your file is not Windows-1252 after all. Could you check it on https://www.freeformatter.com/convert-file-encoding.html?

Comment: Not working as my file is bigger than 2MB

Comment: Could work with ```chardet```, although a bit hacky. Edited the answer.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Run ```pip install chardet```, and use the code above. Post the error message if it doesn't work :)